# jenkins on Ubuntu 14.04 and rael-gc RVM repo - bundle not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, rvm

I'm trying to get jenkins running on a worker node for testing some Rails projects on Ubuntu 14.04. I've installed RVM per [these docs](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/11/how-to-install-rvm-ruby-version-manager.html). When I launch a build from the Jenkins "master", the console output from the node build produces the output below. The home directory for the jenkins user contains a .rvm directory which was copied from a backup. Definitely an older install of rvm. Should that matter? I'm not familiar with rvm.

```
...   
$ bash -c export
$ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
$ bash -c "test -f ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
[PIMS] $ bash -c " source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create . && export > rvm.env"
Using /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5
[PIMS] $ /bin/bash +x +e /tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh
GemWrappers: Can not wrap missing file: bundle
GemWrappers: Can not wrap missing file: bundler
GemWrappers: Can not wrap missing file: rb2db 

unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb, skipping    
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to US-ASCII for lib/bundler/vendor/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb, skipping

Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
Successfully installed rb2db-0.2.2 
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.1...
Installing ri documentation for rb2db-0.2.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.16.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rb2db-0.2.2...
/tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh: line 70: rvm: command not found
/tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh: line 77: bundle: command not found
/tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh: line 89: bundle: command not found
/tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh: line 90: bundle: command not found
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: 184: /usr/bin/xvfb-run: bundle: not found
/tmp/jenkins1009584960163749179.sh: line 108: tmp/failures.log: No such file or directory
grep: tmp/failing_specs.log: No such file or directory
...
```

When I run `which` from the command line, as the jenkins user, these commands turn up fine. Where could the problem be?

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin:
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5@global/bin:
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.5/bin:/bin:/sbin:
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:
/opt/instantclient_12_2:/usr/share/rvm/bin


[jenkins@node1 ~/workspace]
$ which rvm
/usr/share/rvm/bin/rvm

[jenkins@node1 ~/workspace]
$ which bundle
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin/bundle

[jenkins@node1 ~/workspace]
$ which rb2db
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bin/rb2dnb

[jenkins@node1 ~/workspace]
$ which xvfb-run
/usr/bin/xvfb-run
```